# if match with multiple columns in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a two tables, In Table 2 columns from B to F need to be matched from Table 1 columns from A to G. If matched then the status is "YES" if not matched then the status is "NO".

I am achieving the my output the following formula in Excel

```
G2=IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT((TABLE1!A$2:A$18=B2)*(TABLE1!B$2:B$18=C2))>0,IF(B2="Banana",D2=1,D2>1),SUMPRODUCT((TABLE1!B$2:B$18=C2)*(TABLE1!D$2:D$18=E2))>0,SUMPRODUCT((TABLE1!B$2:B$18=C2)*(TABLE1!E$2:G$18=F2))>0),"YES","NO")
```

but How can I apply the same in thing Power Query.

[image]

- Example for line item 2; (In Table 2 Data) The item is 123 the fruit list is "Avocado" with area code is "3100" it's matched to my master data Table 1 therefore the status is "YES".
- Example for line item 5; (In Table 2 Data) The item is 126 the fruit list is "Avocado" with area code is "West" it's not matched to my master data Table 1 therefore the status is "NO".

The "Avocado" "area code" belongs to only the following sales code (EU01,US,UK).

- Example for line item 19; The item is 56 the fruit list is "watermelon" doesn't have a area code. Please refer the above mentioned snapshot.

Match criteria: The matching selection criteria is "Fruit list" and "area code" in both tables.

Qty columns conditions; The qty columns shouldn't be blanks or 0. it's always greater than 1 expect the Banana with area code "PP1 and "KP1" its always equal to 1.

Sales code conditions; The sales code columns shouldn't be blanks or 0.

File attached for your reference.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/8b4cnamqzsk2rannvowkk/POER-BI-DATA-SOF.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=zt7y1rg2di1b53r6ta2kb3jj0

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. This is my first post so could you please advise anyone; Is there any issue or not clear my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for including sufficient detail in your question.

- You can try the code below, it gives me your expected output. I don't know how performant this code will be if you're working with a lot of rows since I can't test it. It might better to use `Table.NestedJoin` instead of `Table.Contains`, although `Table.Contains` probably stops checking once a match has been found, which is better in this scenario.
- I don't think you said anything in your question about checking whether the value for `SALES CODE` in TABLE2 is in any of the values for columns `SALES CODE 1`, `SALES CODE 2`, `SALES CODE 3` in TABLE1. I think that's what this bit `SUMPRODUCT((TABLE1!B$2:B$18=C2)*(TABLE1!E$2:G$18=F2))>0` in your Excel formula is doing.
- Obviously, you will need to replace `table1` and `table2` in the code below with your own code/data, as mine are just hard coded examples.
- I recommend that you try it with as much real data as you can just to ensure that the code works and that the `STATUS` column always contains the value you expect it to contain.
- You can turn the `TRUE/FALSE` values into `YES/NO` with `Table.TransformColumns`. I've kept them as `TRUE/FALSE` for now.

---

```
let
    table1 = Table.FromRows({
        {"Avocado", "3100", 1, "EN", "EU01", "US", "UK"},
        {"Avocado", "3200", 1, "EN", "EU01", "US", "UK"},
        {"Avocado", "3300", 1, "EN", "EU01", "US", "UK"},
        {"Avocado", "4500", 1, "EN", "EU01", "US", "UK"},
        {"Avocado", "8900", 1, "EN", "EU01", "US", "UK"},
        {"Star Fruit", "WEST", 1, "EN", "INDIA01", "INDIA02", "NA"},
        {"Star Fruit", "NORTH", 1, "EN", "INDIA01", "INDIA02", "NA"},
        {"Star Fruit", "EAST", 1, "EN", "INDIA01", "INDIA02", "NA"},
        {"Star Fruit", "SOUTH", 1, "EN", "INDIA01", "INDIA02", "NA"},
        {"Banana", "KP1", 1, "EN", "XX1", "NA", "NA"},
        {"Banana", "PP1", 1, "EN", "XX2", "NA", "NA"},
        {"Apple", "444", 1, "EN", "BAN03", "NA", "NA"},
        {"Orange", "555", 1, "EN", "BAN03", "NA", "NA"},
        {"Orange", "555", 1, "EN", "BAN04", "NA", "NA"},
        {"Orange", "555", 1, "EN", "BAN05", "NA", "NA"},
        {"Plum", "123", 1, "EN", "BAN03", "NA", "NA"},
        {"Watermelon", "", 1, "EN", "EU01", "US", "UK"}
    }, type table [FRUIT LIST = text, AREA CODE = text, QTY = Int64.Type, LANGUAGE = text, SALES CODE 1 = text, SALES CODE 2 = text, SALES CODE 3 = text]),

    table2 = Table.FromRows({
        {"123", "Avocado", "3100", 100, "EN", "EU01"},
        {"124", "Avocado", "3100", 100, "EN", "US"},
        {"125", "Avocado", "3100", 100, "EN", "UK"},
        {"126", "Avocado", "WEST", 100, "EN", "UK"},
        {"127", "Avocado", "3100", 1, "EN", "UK"},
        {"128", "Avocado", "3100", null, "EN", "UK"},
        {"129", "Avocado", "3100", 100, " ", "UK"},
        {"130", "Avocado", "3100", 100, "EN", "INDIA01"},
        {"131", "Avocado", "3100", 100, "EN", ""},
        {"234", "Star Fruit", "WEST", 200, "EN", "INDIA01"},
        {"235", "Star Fruit", "NORTH", 100, "EN", "INDIA01"},
        {"236", "Star Fruit", "EAST", 43, "EN", "INDIA01"},
        {"237", "Star Fruit", "SOUTH", 56, "EN", "INDIA01"},
        {"238", "Star Fruit", "WEST", 78, "EN", "INDIA02"},
        {"239", "Star Fruit", "NORTH", 99, "EN", "INDIA02"},
        {"240", "Star Fruit", "EAST", 133, "EN", "INDIA02"},
        {"241", "Star Fruit", "SOUTH", 45, "EN", "INDIA02"},
        {"56", "Watermelon", "", 100, "EN", "UK"}
    }, type table [ITEM = text, FRUIT LIST = text, AREA CODE = text, QTY = Int64.Type, LANGUAGE = text, SALES CODE = text]),

    statusColumn = Table.AddColumn(table2, "STATUS", (currentRow) =>

        // Check quantity first since it should be a quick/cheap comparison, especially with short-circuit evaluation.
        currentRow[QTY] <> null and (if currentRow[FRUIT LIST] = "Banana" then currentRow[QTY] = 1 else currentRow[QTY] > 1)

        // FRUIT LIST && AREA CODE matches any TABLE1 row?
        and Table.Contains(table1, currentRow[[FRUIT LIST], [AREA CODE]], {"FRUIT LIST", "AREA CODE"})

        // AREA CODE && LANGUAGE matches any TABLE1 row?
        and Table.Contains(table1, currentRow[[AREA CODE], [LANGUAGE]], {"AREA CODE", "LANGUAGE"})

        // AREA CODE && SALES CODE matches any TABLE1 row?
        and Table.Contains(table1, currentRow, (table1row as record, currentRow as record) =>
        
            table1row[AREA CODE] = currentRow[AREA CODE]
            
            // SALES CODE needs custom treatment as there is no SALES CODE column in TABLE1
            and List.Contains(Record.FieldValues(table1row[[SALES CODE 1], [SALES CODE 2], [SALES CODE 3]]), currentRow[SALES CODE])
        )

    , type logical)

in
    statusColumn
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I thought it's easy to do it Power BI but reality not.Yes, In table 2; the Sales code need to be match from Tables 1 (from Sales Code 1 , sales code 2 and Sales code 3). I will tested quickly and updated the feed back to you.

Comment: could you please help me . I am new to POWER BI. I know little bit about the merge tables. where I need to apply the above mentioned code in Power BI? In new measure columns against each tables? Please advise.

Comment: Please advise anyone how can I use the above mentioned code. I try to place the code in advance editor but I got so many error message.

Comment: @Jack, #1 I think you need to create queries (using `Home > Edit queries` in Power BI) for your tables `TABLE1` and `TABLE2`. If your tables are in an Excel workbook, google how to import them (it should basically involve `Excel.Workbook(pathToWorkbook)`) #2 Then create a third query in which you copy-paste the code from my answer into the Advanced Editor, but replace the `table1 = ...` and `table2 = ...` sections in my code with references to the queries created in step 1. -- That should be all you need to do. If you get error messages, you'll need to share them (or include a screenshot).